# How to draw a dynamic math number line using JS or/and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, web

I need to draw a number line, that can allows to ask an input and draw the point in the line, or move some point over the line.

like this example:
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/multiplication-division/multiplication_fun/e/number_line

i tried to use canvas but i can't get it, because i never used it before.

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

here the JS:

```
 $(function() {
      var canvas = $('canvas')[0];
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var w = canvas.width = 700; 
      var h = canvas.height = 400;
      var x0 = w/2;
      var starti=-10;
      var endi=10;
      var interval = 20; //10 -> 20 ... 15 -> x 
      var step = 2;
      var steps = 5;

      with(ctx) {

        fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
        fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        fill();
        beginPath();
        lineWidth = 2;
        strokeStyle = '#000';
        moveTo(w/7, h/2);
        lineTo(6*w/7, h/2);
        stroke();  
        moveTo(w/7, h/2);
        lineTo(w/7+10, h/2+10); //left arrow bottom line
        stroke();
        moveTo(w/7, h/2);
        lineTo(w/7+10, h/2-10); //left arrow top line
        stroke();
        moveTo(6*w/7, h/2);
        lineTo(6*w/7-10, h/2+10); //right arrow bot line
        stroke();
        moveTo(6*w/7, h/2);
        lineTo(6*w/7-10, h/2-10); //right arrow top line
        stroke();

        for(var i = starti;i <= endi; i++) {
          beginPath();
          strokeStyle = '#8C8C8C';
          lineWidth = 2;
          moveTo(w/2 + i * interval, h/2 - 10);
          lineTo(w/2 + i * interval, h/2 + 10);
          fillStyle = '#000';
          fillText(i/10, (w/2 + i * interval )- 5, h/2 + 25);
          if(!i) {

            strokeStyle = '#F25050';
          }
          fill();
          stroke();
        }

      }
      drawOperation(x0,step, steps);
    });
```

doesn't matter if you know another solution instead of canvas.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any example code? Any previous attempts? Anything?

Comment: i tried using canvas and javascript, but the problem is that i don't know how to use it.
I gonna paste the code.

Comment: Why don't you try jQuery UI slider? With some styles, it will work for you.

Comment: oh god, that's an awesome idea, how i don't get it before, maybe that could work, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. There is an answer somewhere here in this website that shows how to add lines and numbers. Sadly, I don't remember the title :/